# Pyplot InvalidIndexError with pandas dataset but i don't know why

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

it's the first question I ask here, so forgive me for the various mistakes I will surely make.
I open this thread because I have a problem with a piece of code that works for other colleagues, while it didn't intend to work with me.

```
ax2.plot(x,lauxate[["YearS","Grad"]][mask_m].groupby("YearS").sum(),
        c="r",label="man",alpha=0.5)
```

When i try to execute, it throws me this error (the image on this post)

Any suggestion?
Thanks

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdd2p.png)

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example. In short something is missing or wrongly indexed in your data but we don't have the data, so difficult to help ;)

Comment: Please don't add errors as image. Show them as text, preferably the full error trace. (A first guess would be that you tried to use a nonexisting column name.)